How do I test instantiation outside a function with patching in Python
I have a file that looks roughly like this:
bar.py
from foo import foo # function that returns an int
from dog import Dog

dog_foo = 4 * foo()
my_dog = Dog(dog_foo)

...

I want to test that the my_dog object is properly instantiated with the results of foo() times 4. This is a unit test, so I'm trying to avoid testing the internals of foo(). I'd like to in fact, patch foo, so that the internals definitely don't matter.
However, once I've imported anything from bar into my test, the instantiation lines have already run. Therefore, I need to somehow import inside of a patched block. What exactly should I be patching here?
I tried this, but it didn't seem to be using the patch:
with mock.patch("foo.foo") as mock_foo:
   mock_foo.return_value = 5
   from bar import my_dog

I have also tried this:
with mock.patch("bar.foo") as mock_foo:
   mock_foo.return_value = 5
   from bar import my_dog

This must be possible right? What am I missing?

A unit test doesn't really have to test the arithmetic capabilities of the compiler.  I think you can trust that the expression is valid.  What you need to check is that foo works right.  Right?

I want to check to make sure that I have properly instantiated Dog with 4 times the result of foo. i am testing that foo works elsewhere.

If you're validating foo elsewhere, then can't you just check that dog_foo == 4*foo()?  I just have the sense that you're making this harder than is sensible.

That would mean testing the internals of foo which is not appropriate for a unit test. In any case, in my real-world problem, foo measures something that varies depending on where it is run. So, the result is not predictable enough for to rely on it here.

Why is the expression 4 * foo() important, rather than an implementation detail of my_dog? What property of my_dog that results from that particular argument can you test for?

I test the initialization of Dog() in unit tests elsewhere. It's important to make sure that all code has coverage, including something as small as multiplying a value by 4.

You don't test built-ins of python. If the value returned by foo() is based on the environment, then you patch environment variable instead.

I'm not testing built-ins. I'm testing that my code multiplies a variable by 4 as expected. The implementation of foo() or what it does should not matter at all to this test.

You are supposed to test the return value of foo() by patching the environment variable. But instead, you are testing multiplication operator which is a built-in.

For anyone else who finds this and is similarly stuck, I figured it out!
I am using pytest, and the bar.py file was being executed at test collection time. I had another test file that was importing a value from bar.py. In order to collect the tests, pytest was executing this import. This meant that bar.py was executing at test collection time and was known to sys.modules. Therefore, it didn't need to execute again, and was just returning the already computed value rather than re-executing.
I fixed this by reloading the module instead of the mocked context. The test code looks like this:
import sys
from importlib import reload
from unittest import mock

def test_my_dog:
    with mock.patch("foo.foo") as mock_foo:
        mock_foo.return_value = 5
        reload(sys.modules.get('bar'))
        from bar import my_dog
    assert mock_foo.call_count == 1
    assert my_dog.dog_foo == 20
    reload(sys.modules.get('bar')) # This resets it for the next run.


Based on your comments, you are asking an XY problem. What you really want to test is, what return values that the function foo can return based on the value of an environment variable. There is no reason to test if you can multiply the return value with 4. You are not supposed to test multiplication operator or the value that a global variable holds. You should only test the functionality of your code.
import os

import pytest


@pytest.parametrize('envvar, value', [('DEV', '0'), ('PROD', '1')])
def test_foo(envvar: str, value: str) -> None:
    os.environ['environment'] = envvar
    assert foo() == int(value)

The statement dog_foo = 4 * foo() will be automatically covered by the tests when you will set mock environment variables for the tests by using a module like pytest-env.
